Can't build fultterfire_cli using Firebase CLI
I'm trying to Add Firebase to Flutter. I logged in to Firebase and it's Ok. When I execute this line :
> dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
It gives me this error:

Failed to build flutterfire_cli:flutterfire:
/C:/Users/Gamal/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/xml-6.5.0/lib/src/xml_events/converters/event_decoder.dart:104:20:
Error: A value of type 'Result' can't be assigned to a
variable of type 'Failure'.

'Result' is from 'package:petitparser/src/core/result.dart' ('/C:/Users/Gamal/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/petitparser-6.0.2/lib/src/core/result.dart').
'XmlEvent' is from 'package:xml/src/xml_events/event.dart' ('/C:/Users/Gamal/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/xml-6.5.0/lib/src/xml_events/event.dart').
'Failure' is from 'package:petitparser/src/core/result.dart' ('/C:/Users/Gamal/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/petitparser-6.0.2/lib/src/core/result.dart').
previous = current;
**                    ^


I searched online, tried some deactivate and activate and nothing happens.
